# How to generate IntelliJ JUnit json auto report?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, report, allure

I'm new with IntelliJ. I have run my test cases with JUnit but the report is not generate automatically. There is a button to generate the JUnit report manually:

[image]

I would like obtain this report automatically, not manually, and with .json format to generate the allure report. But I can't find the action.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither of the two features (support for saving results in JSON or saving the report automatically) exists in IntelliJ IDEA. What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you may actually need a continuous integration tool.